# How to run a single operation for multiple files selected

Tags: python

Selected Files (3)
[Menu Selection Send To ----](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1GK3.jpg)
[Result, Program will run for how many files are selected for this example it is 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkbkS.png)

I have made an addition to windows registry and made a right click menu option for files. I attached a program to the option that will attach the file to an email and send me the file. When I select multiple files it will create multiple emails. What I want is for all the files to attach to a single email.

What I've tried:
1. I have tried a for loop in python script for sys.argv[n] / Didn't work because the program will run for each individual file selected

Comment: You need to add all the files to a single `sys.argv` list, not run the script separately for each file.

Comment: So this is a separate program for sending the email? You could create the email and then for `filename in sys.argv[1:]` add_attachment(filename)`. You really need to post a simplified program so we can talk about the solution sensibly. The GUI part doesn't matter, just the email assembly part.

Comment: _the program will run for each individual file selected_ why is that bad? If that code is juste adding an attachment, sounds like its exactly what you want.

Comment: @tdelaney It will send me multiple emails.

Comment: @Barmar that's the one thing I tried. I'll upload a video of what is happening.

Comment: No need to upload a video. Either your GUI is calling the program mulitple times with a single attachment, or your program is generating multiple emails. You need to figure out which and then post a small example program that has the same problem.

Comment: I added pictures since the video is choppy. I'm really not sure how to recreate the issue into a script since the issue isn't because of the script but how many times windows decides to run the program.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a batch file.
2. insert `@echo off cls command_path/command.exe %*`  into the batch file
3. Go to command location in windows registry and change the default value to the newly created batch file.
4. Continue if you don't want the command.exe location to be a part of the files sent
5. Create an array named files. ex. files = []
6. create a for loop to append to files ex. `for i in sys.argv: if i != sys.argv[0]: files.append(i)`
7. The files value will be inserted accordingly to the part of the api structure that handles attachments. Make sure to put it in as *files if you're not putting it into a list then files will work just fine.
   (For those who are not in the know. The * is a spread operator. More examples on spread operators can be found easily by looking up spread operator.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with Windows Explorer.  You need to tell it you can handle multiple names.  Have you registered your handler with an "open" verb?  If you register it with the "OpenWithList" verb, then Explorer should send the whole list to one executable.  I'm looking up the exact setting now.

Yes, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.mkv\OpenWithList\xxx.py`.

Comment: Okay, So I should add \OpenWithList\xxx.py to the current location of my program? Right now I have my program connected to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe\ShellNew\SendTo---\command. So I should do *HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe\ShellNew\SendTo---\OpenWithList\command* ?

P.S. the .mkv were just example files I want it to run on any file.

Comment: What I'm seeing is that I don't have that option unless I am in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*classtype*\OpenWithList\ I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

### SUMMARY

1. In Registry put the target program as **Context Menu Create File.exe** which writes **reg.txt** file.
2. In your main program loop every 1 second to check if **reg.txt** exists. If it exists, kill the **Context Menu Create File.exe** and delete the **reg.txt** file. Then copy the selected file paths and manipulate with them.
3. If your program loops to check for **reg.txt**, then you need to start the program before executing context menu either on startup or manually.

> I did this with [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com).
>
> These 2 AutoHotkey scripts below allow you to add a `Send Email Attachments` context menu item in Windows Explorer to send multiple attachments to a single mail message window.
>
> You can leave all variable values as they are, but if you want to change the `contextMenu` value and `program` name then see **3.1.**

### INSTRUCTIONS:

Create 2 files in the same directory:

1. Create 1st program **Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.ahk**

   1. `RunAsAdmin` Label ensures that the script runs as admin (fixes adding Registry values).

      1. The `If (!A_IsAdmin)` checks if current user is **NOT** admin, A_IsAdmin is a built in AutoHotkey variable that returns 1 if user is admin, 0 otherwise.
      2. `Run, \*RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"` ***RunAs** parameter runs the script as admin, **"%A_ScriptFullPath%"** gets the full path of the current executing script.
      3. `ExitApp` exits the current script instance running without admin privileges.
      4. Because the `Run` command runs the script again with admin privileges it will skip the `IF` condition and continue executing code below.
   2. `ContextMenuCreateFile:`  Label creates a **Context Menu Create File.exe** which creates a file **reg.txt** and exits **Context Menu Create File.exe** after it has written the file **reg.txt**. Make sure you specify where your `Ahk2Exe.exe` path is in the `RunWait` command.
   3. `Add To Context Menu:`  Label adds the Registry entry which runs **Context Menu Create File.exe**.

      1. Set the `contextMenu` variable to what needs to be displayed in the Context Menu. (The `program` name is set to `contextMenu`)
      2. Set the `regPath` to your desired Registry path.
      3. When it executes the `MsgBox`, check if the command is added to the Registry in the address bar.
   4. `CreateStartupShortcut:` Label creates the shortcut of the main program **Send Email Attachments.exe** in Startup folder.

### Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.ahk

```
; =============Recommended Settings=============
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#Warn
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SetTitleMatchMode Fast
DetectHiddenWindows Off
DetectHiddenText On
#WinActivateForce
#NoTrayIcon
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1
#Persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
; =============Recommended Settings=============

AddToContextMenuAndCreateStartupShortcut:
RunAsAdmin:  ; =============RunAsAdmin=============
If (!A_IsAdmin)  ; IF NOT Admin
{
    Run, *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"  ; Run script as admin
    ExitApp  ; Exit the current instance running without admin privileges
}



ContextMenuCreateFile:  ; =============ContextMenuCreateFile=============
contextMenuCreateFileAhk := 
(LTrim
"#NoEnv
#NoTrayIcon
#SingleInstance Force
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SetBatchLines -1

ContextMenuCreateFile:
FileDelete, reg.txt
FileAppend, , reg.txt
ExitApp
Return"
)  ; contextMenuCreateFileAhk
FileDelete, Context Menu Create File.exe  ; DEL Context Menu Create File.exe
FileDelete, Context Menu Create File.ahk  ; DEL Context Menu Create File.ahk
FileAppend, %contextMenuCreateFileAhk%, Context Menu Create File.ahk  ; MAKE Context Menu Create File.ahk
RunWait, C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\Compiler\Ahk2Exe.exe /in "Context Menu Create File.ahk" /out "Context Menu Create File.exe"  ; Convert AHK to EXE
FileDelete, Context Menu Create File.ahk  ; DEL Context Menu Create File.ahk



AddToContextMenu:  ; =============AddToContextMenu=============
path := ""  ; path
program := "Context Menu Create File"  ; program
contextMenu := "Send Email Attachments"  ; contextMenu
regPath := "HKCR\*\shell"  ; regPath
StringReplace, regKey, contextMenu, %A_Space%, , A  ; regKey
regKey := 0 regKey  ; regKey
Loop, Files, %program%.exe, F  ; Find Program.exe In Current Dir
{
    path := A_LoopFileLongPath  ; Set Program Path
}
cmd := 
(LTrim
"reg add """ regPath "\" regKey """ /ve /t REG_SZ /d """ contextMenu """ /f
reg add """ regPath "\" regKey "\command"" /ve /t REG_SZ /d ""\""" path "\""`"" /f"
)  ; Registry
FileDelete, Add To Context Menu.bat  ; CREATE Add To Context Menu.bat
FileAppend, %cmd%, Add To Context Menu.bat  ; CREATE Add To Context Menu.bat
RunWait, Add To Context Menu.bat, , Hide  ; RUN Add To Context Menu.bat (*RunAs ADMIN)
FileDelete, Add To Context Menu.bat  ; DEL Add To Context Menu.bat
SoundPlay, C:\Windows\Media\Windows Pop-up Blocked.wav  ; SUCCESS
Run, regedit  ; regedit
WinWait, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; Registry
Sleep, 333
ControlSetText, Edit1, %regPath%\%regKey%\command, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlFocus, Edit1, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlSend, Edit1, {Enter}, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlSend, SysListView321, {Control Down}{NumpadAdd}{Control Up}, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlSend, SysListView321, {F5}, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
MsgBox, 262192, CHECK, Check If Added %contextMenu% To Registry  ; CHECK



CreateStartupShortcut:  ; =============CreateStartupShortcut=============
path := ""  ; path
program := contextMenu  ; program
Loop, Files, %program%.exe, F  ; Find Program.exe In Current Dir
{
    path := A_LoopFileLongPath  ; Set Program Path
}
FileCreateShortcut, %path%, %A_Startup%\%program%.lnk  ; Create Startup Shortcut
Run, %A_Startup%, , Max  ; Check If Shortcut Created
Run, %program%.exe  ; Run Program
MsgBox, 262144, CHECK, Check If Shortcut Created  ; DONE
ExitApp  ; ExitApp
Return
```

2. Create 2nd program **Send Email Attachments.ahk** which is the main program.

   1. Here a `Loop` is created and checks every 1 second if **reg.txt** exists.
   2. `IfExist, reg.txt` it kills the **Context Menu Create File.exe** and deletes the **reg.txt**.
   3. Then it activates explorer.exe window and copies all selected file paths to **CLIPBOARD**.
   4. `If CLIPBOARD contains .,\` to make sure **CLIPBOARD** contains path **"\"** with extension **"."**.
   5. The list of selected files is saved in `selectedFiles` variable.
   6. Then a temporary directory `C:\at` is made, to copy the selected files to and remove the commas **","** in file names so that Thunderbird can input them through CLI (to keep original file names on disk).
   7. The Loop below `attachs := ""` loops through selected files, gets the file names, replaces commas **","** with a **%A_Space%** which is a built in variable for space character. It also removes double spaces if they get created with the previous command.
   8. The `newFilePath` joins temporary path `C:\at` with the file name.
   9. Then with `FileCopy` the selected files are copied from `oldFilePath` to `newFilePath` and concatenated to `attachs` string with comma **","** as delimiter, because Thunderbird CLI separates attachments with comma.
   10. `StringTrimRight` removes the last comma from `attachs` string.
   11. Then `Run, thunderbird.exe` is executed with `attachs` (list of selected files) as attachment parameter. (If the command doesn't open Thunderbird then put full path to Thunderbird, ex: `Run, C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe` with the same parameters)
   12. Last, `WinWait` and `WinWaitClose` wait for the Thunderbird New Message to appear and close and after closing the window the temporary directory `C:\at` is deleted.

### Send Email Attachments.ahk

```
; =============Recommended Settings=============
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#Warn
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SetTitleMatchMode Fast
DetectHiddenWindows Off
DetectHiddenText On
#WinActivateForce
#NoTrayIcon
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1
#Persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
; =============Recommended Settings=============

SendEmailAttachments:
Loop  ; Loop Start
{
    Sleep, 1000  ; Fix High CPU
    IfExist, reg.txt  ; IF reg.txt EXIST
    {
        Loop, 15  ; Fix Opening 2 Compose Windows
        {
            Run, cmd /c taskkill /im "Context Menu Create File.exe" /f, , Hide  ; Fix Opening 2 Compose Windows
        }
        Sleep, 1000  ; Fix Opening 2 Compose Windows
        FileDelete, reg.txt  ; DEL reg.txt
        WinActivate, ahk_class CabinetWClass ahk_exe explorer.exe  ; Explorer
        CLIPBOARD := ""  ; Clear Clipboard
        Send, {Control Down}{c}{Control Up}  ; Copy File Paths
        ClipWait, 0  ; Clip Wait
        If CLIPBOARD contains .,\  ; IF CLIPBOARD contains .,\
        {
            selectedFiles := CLIPBOARD  ; selectedFiles
            FileRemoveDir, C:\at, 1  ; Remove C:\at
            FileCreateDir, C:\at  ; Create C:\at
            attachs := ""  ; attachs
            Loop, Parse, selectedFiles, `n, `r  ; Loop Start selectedFiles
            {
                oldFilePath := A_LoopField  ; oldFilePath
                newFilePath := A_LoopField  ; newFilePath
                SplitPath, newFilePath, fileNameExt  ; Get File Name With Ext
                StringReplace, fileNameExt, fileNameExt, `,, %A_Space%, A  ; Replace , - " "
                StringReplace, fileNameExt, fileNameExt, %A_Space%%A_Space%, %A_Space%, A  ; Replace "  " - " "
                newFilePath := "C:\at\" fileNameExt  ; newFilePath
                FileCopy, %oldFilePath%, %newFilePath%, 1  ; Copy oldFilePath -> C:\at\fileNameExt
                attachs .= newFilePath ","  ; attachs .= %newFilePath%,
            }
            StringTrimRight, attachs, attachs, 1  ; Remove Last ,
            Run, thunderbird.exe -compose "to='john@example.com'`,subject='Attachments'`,body='Multiple attachments added.'`,attachment='%attachs%'", , Hide  ; Send Email Attachments
            WinWait, Write: ahk_class MozillaWindowClass ahk_exe thunderbird.exe  ; Wait New Message
            Sleep, 333
            WinWaitClose, Write: ahk_class MozillaWindowClass ahk_exe thunderbird.exe  ; Wait Close New Message
            Sleep, 333
            FileRemoveDir, C:\at, 1  ; Remove C:\at
        }
    }
}
Return
```

3. Convert both **Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.ahk** and **Send Email Attachments.ahk** to **EXE** files in the same directory using **Ahk2Exe.exe** --> (find in Start Menu, just browse file and hit convert)
4. Execute the **`Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.exe`**
5. Select files, right click and the **Send Email Attachments** context menu item should appear.